# VUEJS I want to stop fields caching on component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having a problem my browser caches are loading on the fields of my vuejs component. I'm using vuejs with element framework. Below is the picture of fields which are autofilled.

[image: Here are the fields which are auto-filled due to cache]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute `autocomplete` and setting the value to `off`.

Example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

This essentially tells the browser to leave that input alone for auto completion purposes.

This will work for any other type of input too.

I hope this helps.